# Linking Directories with special character '(' using Maven

Tags: java, maven

Hello I'm using Maven to generate an RPM, and I'm facing a problem that I think it will be easy to solve.

In the pom.xml file of my project I'm trying to create a softlink to a directory, and according to http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/source-params.html, I have made something like this:

```
<mapping>
    <directory>${dir.opt}/myproject/lib/nbi/xslt/6.1.5(b)</directory>
    <sources>
       <softlinkSource>
          <location>${dir.opt}/myproject/lib/nbi/xslt/6.1.5(a)</location>
       </softlinkSource>
   </sources>
</mapping>
```

When I try to compile and pack my project into an rpm I get the following  output

```
...
[WARNING] /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.60423: line 117: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[WARNING] error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.60423 (%install)
[WARNING]     Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.60423 (%install)
...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

I'm thinking the problem is occuring because the directory path has the special character `(`, so I've tried the following, without success though.

```
<mapping>
    <directory>${dir.opt}/myproject/lib/nbi/xslt/6.1.5\(b\)</directory>
    <sources>
       <softlinkSource>
          <location>${dir.opt}/myproject/lib/nbi/xslt/6.1.5\(a\)</location>
       </softlinkSource>
   </sources>
</mapping>
```

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: i'd certainly refrain from using `(` `)` in your directory names. use something more sensible like `-` or `_`.  but to your problem, have you tried double escaping it? possibly even triple to escape the escape.  `\\(`, `\\\(`

Comment: The thing is I really need to use the ( and ) in the directory path name , because I'm using it later. I've tryed the double escaping, and the triple and the problem persists :/

Comment: if you need it later, couldn't you just do a `.replaceAll("_", "(").append(")")` or something similar?

Comment: I'll your workaround, till I figure it out another way . Thank you